# Build collection of models from standard query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

In my Laravel 4.2 app I have several models of which use Eloquent ORM. I usually access the data through the standard functions (e.g. `::get()`).

The issue I have is that with ORM I'm producing lots of queries when perhaps just a single custom query would suffice.

My question is, is there a way to execute a custom query but have those results populate into the my pre-existing Eloquent models.

Comment: You can use DB::raw(), but everything can all be handled by the ORM, except for sub selects queries. With queries being executed and put into collections you will have to manually insert these into your collection, you can use the put method to assign the key of what you want to use.

Comment: Someone on Twitter suggested `hydrate` and `hydrateRaw` of which would take data (or a query) and populate models from them... investigating that now.

Comment: Yes that is almost certainly a possibility.

Comment: Probably you are just using Eloquent the way it shouldn't be used. Unless you have really complex queries stuff going on. Show the code that executes so many queries.